# Regex parsing string substitution question

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to know if there is an easy way for parsing a string like this

```
set   PROMPT = Yes, Master?
```

What I would like to do, is parse one part of this string up to the equal sign and parse the second part after the equal sign into another string.

Comment: Is there always a set? Is there 1 per line? Does a new line mark the end of an answer?

Comment: No there would not always be a set, the other option would be allias. And yes there would be one perl line and a new line would mark the end of the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like...

```
$phrase = 'set   PROMPT = Yes, Master?';
@parts = split /=/, $phrase;
```

or

```
($set, $value) = split /=/, $phrase, 2;
```

*[updated] Changes per comments.*

Comment: +1: Splitting on the equal sign is the best way of doing this. It's simple and easy to understand what's going on.

Comment: No need for \ on =.  Another example: `($set, $value) = split /=/, $phrase, 2;`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but won't this give you EVERYTHING before the `=`? `@parts[0]` = `set   PROMPT `? If I'm missing something please let me know but because of that I think my regular expression is a better solution. I apologize if this comes off the wrong way.

Comment: @daalbert: he never gave any indication that he needed any special handling of the input so I assumed the simplest solution.

Comment: thank you for replying. You are correct. After looking at the question again, your answer is the simplest that meets the specifications. I guess this is a reminder to always carefully read the specs since they don’t always align with how one thinks things should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Try matching this regex `/\s*set\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)\s*$/` and setting the parts with `$1` and `$2`:

```
my $str = 'set   PROMPT = Yes, Master?';
my ($k, $v) = ($1, $2) if $str =~ /\s*set\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*)\s*$/;
print "OK: k=$k, v=$v\n"; OK: k=PROMPT, v=Yes, Master?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($subject =~ m/([^\s]+)\s*=\s*([^\$]+)/img) {
    # $1 = $2
}
```